# How to switch between 2 videos on hover with transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I want my second frame (`.frame2`) to fade into the other video on `mouseover` and fade back into the default one on `mouseout`, but I can't seem to add the transition duration and make it look nice. I want the first video to fade out and have the second video already be there, so no background shown, so the frame always stays the same size to who is looking at it.

Edit: I just tried the CSS way, to put another video element on top on `.frame2` and make it either `display: none;` or `opacity: 0;` and make it `display: block;` or `opacity: 1;` on hover of `.frame2`, but it didn't work. For some reason it doesn't render the video element underneath it.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/zjYMqM)

```
var video1 = 'https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/30858529/preview/stock-footage-cinemagraph-seamless-loop-little-boy-wearing-helmet-and-styrofoam-wings-standing-on-a-skateboard.mp4';
var video2 = 'https://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/30860722/preview/stock-footage-cinemagraph-seamless-loop-little-boy-wearing-helmet-and-styrofoam-wings-standing-on-a-skateboard.mp4';

$('.frame2').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', video2);
});

$('.frame2').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', video1);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use two video elements instead of changing the src? Stack them on top of each other. Fade out the top most on hover.

```js
$('.frame_hover').hover(function() {
  $('.frame2_2').fadeOut(500);
}, function() {
  $('.frame2_2').fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333437;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.frame-container {
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75));
}

.frame1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50.5%) translateY(-49%);
  clip-path: polygon(19% 52%, 40% 52%, 40% 90%, 19% 90%);
}

.frame2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  clip-path: polygon(38% 0, 68% 0, 68% 100%, 38% 100%);
}

.frame3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-51%);
  clip-path: polygon(66% 9%, 88% 9%, 88% 82%, 66% 82%);
}

.frame4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-47%) translateY(-48%);
  clip-path: polygon(86% 0, 100% 0, 100% 29%, 86% 29%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="frame-container">
    <video class="frame1" src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/30858529/preview/stock-footage-cinemagraph-seamless-loop-little-boy-wearing-helmet-and-styrofoam-wings-standing-on-a-skateboard.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
  </div>

  <div class="frame-container">
    <video class="frame4" src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/30858529/preview/stock-footage-cinemagraph-seamless-loop-little-boy-wearing-helmet-and-styrofoam-wings-standing-on-a-skateboard.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
  </div>

  <div class="frame-container frame_hover">
    <video class="frame2 frame2_1" src="https://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/30860722/preview/stock-footage-cinemagraph-seamless-loop-little-boy-wearing-helmet-and-styrofoam-wings-standing-on-a-skateboard.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
    <video class="frame2 frame2_2" src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/30858529/preview/stock-footage-cinemagraph-seamless-loop-little-boy-wearing-helmet-and-styrofoam-wings-standing-on-a-skateboard.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
  </div>

  <div class="frame-container">
    <video class="frame3" src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/30858529/preview/stock-footage-cinemagraph-seamless-loop-little-boy-wearing-helmet-and-styrofoam-wings-standing-on-a-skateboard.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `<video>` tag should be closed with `</video>` rather than `/>`.

Comment: Thanks Turnip! As I said in my edit, I was trying this method out as well, but couldn't figure it out. You're awesome!

Comment: No problem. I think your design looks great BTW. Love that effect.

Comment: Thank you! This is the end result: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/zjYMqM). Do you think the JS could be any cleaner by only using a single function?

Comment: Yeah you could make it much simpler: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmVOXK

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.video-fade-in {
  animation : fade-in .5s ease-in forwards;
}

.video-fade-out {
  animation : fade-out .5s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0.5;
    }
    100% {
      opacity : 1;
    }
}

var video1 = 'https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/30858529/preview/stock-footage-cinemagraph-seamless-loop-little-boy-wearing-helmet-and-styrofoam-wings-standing-on-a-skateboard.mp4';
    var video2 = 'https://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/30860722/preview/stock-footage-cinemagraph-seamless-loop-little-boy-wearing-helmet-and-styrofoam-wings-standing-on-a-skateboard.mp4';

$('#frame2').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('video-fade-out').addClass('video-fade-in').attr('src', video2);
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('video-fade-in').addClass('video-fade-out').attr('src', video1);
});
```

Comment: It gives the same "blinking" effect as my own script, would you have an idea how to add a fadein/out transition effect on these?

Comment: You can edit the fade animation in css as per you need.